# How to create a local repo using a live dvd iso of Centos?

Tags: centos, yum, repository, iso

So let's say am in home dir.

And I do have CENTOS7.iso sitting on my home dir.

Now how do I create a local repo of Centos.

What I did so far is create a dir.

```
# mkdir localrepo

# yum install createrepo

# createrepo localrepo
```

Now what should be my next step at this point ?

Answer (score 1):

The order is:
Mount iso
Copy iso content to hdd
Create .repo file pointing to location of contents from previous step